# How can I fix a "403" error message when trying to install Microsoft Silverlight?

Tags: software-recommendation, moonlight

Please can someone help me so that I can watch BT sport on my Linux Laptop? I can't download Silverlight as I keep getting a 403 message.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding your question by editing it to include the complete and exact text of the error message, as well as a more detailed description of exactly what you did, what you wanted or expected to happen, and what did happen.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is not Linux compatible.  The Linux equivalent is Moonlight.

Please look here: [Moonlight](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/moonlight)

Comment: Moonlight is not used any more as it shut down 2yrs ago!! also still get the same 403 message saying i do not have authority to do this download!